# How to format a single cell in a multicell fpdf table

Tags: php, cell, fpdf

I'm using a multicell table with fpdf
and I want to format the value of a cell with bold letters depending on a condition

Example:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Row(array("","IDUSER","NAME","AGE"); //header of the table<BR>
do {
    if($myrow["age"] >30)
         $age=<b>$myrow["age"]; //value in bold letter<br>
    else
        $age=$myrow["age"];

    $pdf->Row(array($n,$myrow["id_user"],$myrow["name"],$age));

} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `SetFont` with 'B' to get bold and without 'B' for regular before displaying text :

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Row(array("","IDUSER","NAME","AGE"); //header of the table<BR>
do<br>
{<BR>
    if($myrow["age"] >30)<br>
      { $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);  // ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■ BOLD
        $age=$myrow["age"]; //value in bold letter<br>
      }
    else{ <br>
          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);  // ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■ REGULAR.
          $age=$myrow["age"];<br>
        } 
    $pdf->Row(array($n,$myrow["id_user"],$myrow["name"],$age));<br>

} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);<br>
```

Another approach :

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Row(array("","IDUSER","NAME","AGE"); //header of the table<BR>
do<br>
{<BR>
    if($myrow["age"] >30)<br>
      { $font = "B"; // ◄■■■ BOLD FONT.
        $age=$myrow["age"]; //value in bold letter<br>
      }
    else{ <br>
          $font = ""; // ◄■■■ REGULAR FONT.
          $age=$myrow["age"];<br>
        } 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial',$font,10); // ◄■■■ SET FONT.
    $pdf->Row(array($n,$myrow["id_user"],$myrow["name"],$age));<br>

} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);<br>
```

Comment: I was trying this suggestion but it doesn't work. Set font affects all the cells

Comment: @user3333911, it should affect the cells only of the row being displayed.

Comment: @user3333911, I edited my answer, give it a try to the second approach.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I try again with a regular set font just before the if sentence and it works. Gracias por la ayuda.